# Custom Sliverappbar is not working in flutter

Tags: flutter, sliverappbar, flutter-sliverappbar

[image]

In this screen, I have implemented sliver appbar.

- On swipe up Pizza hut text will be set on toolbar. and 'Sec 16, Dwarka, New Delhi' to 'Now open' text layout will be hide. and the offers tabbar will be set below the toolbar.
- I tried to set tabbar in bottom property of sliverapp bar. but it is not set correctly as we want.

Code is too lengthy and also we have used custom text and fonts. So for that reason I'm not posting my code. Suggest me by sample code. we will replace our code. Thank you.

Comment: Please paste your code through a github gist at least here or else I don't think anyone would help.